# Constructing a Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question says: Suppose that there are two goats on an island initially. The number of goats on the island doubles every year. Construct a recurrence relation for the number of goats on the island at the start of the $n$th year, assuming that $n$ goats are removed during the $n$th year for each $n \geq 3$.

My approach:

$a_0 = 2$, $a_1 = 4$, $a_2 = 8$, and $a_n = 2a_{n-1} - n$

Assuming that this is correct, I need to solve this recurrence relation. This is the part that has me stuck. I know that each year will have $2^{k+1}$ goats, but I don't know what to do with the minus $n$.

Comment: Don't you think it is $a_n = 2a_{n-1} - (n-1)$ ?